# Time- and space- efficient array multiplication in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given NumPy arrays `R` and `S` with shapes `(m, d)` and `(m, n, d)` respectively, I would like to compute an array `P` of shape `(m, n)` whose `(i, j)`-th entry is `np.dot(R[i, :] , S[i, j, :])`.

Doing a double for-loop would not need any extra space (apart from the `m * n` space for `P`), but would not be time-efficient.

Using broadcasting, I could do `P = np.sum(R[:, np.newaxis, :] * S, axis=2)`, but this would cost extra `m * n * d` space.

What is the most time- and space-efficient way to do this?

Comment: Nitpick: I'm not sure if the *time efficiency* is actually different, just the constant factors are much lower using the broadcasting approach.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree, but I only said time-efficiency, not time-*complexity*.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I think I am using the terminology incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`einsum` is another of the usual suspects

```
m, n, d = 100, 100, 100
>>> R = np.random.random((m, d))
>>> S = np.random.random((m, n, d))
>>> np.einsum('md,mnd->mn', R, S)

>>> np.allclose(np.einsum('md,mnd->mn', R, S), (R[:,None,:]*S).sum(axis=-1))
True
>>> from timeit import repeat
>>> repeat('np.einsum("md,mnd->mn", R, S)', globals=globals(), number=1000)
[0.7004671019967645, 0.6925274690147489, 0.6952172230230644]
>>> repeat('(R[:,None,:]*S).sum(axis=-1)', globals=globals(), number=1000)
[3.0512512560235336, 3.0466731210472062, 3.044075728044845]
```

Some indirect evidence that `einsum` isn't too wasteful with the RAM:

```
>>> m, n, d = 1000, 1001, 1002
>>> # Too much for broadcasting:
>>> np.zeros((m, n, d))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
>>> R = np.random.random((m, d))
>>> S = np.random.random((n, d))
>>> np.einsum('md,nd->mn', R, S).shape
(1000, 1001)
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga added some (rather low-tech) evidence that `einsum` doesn't do a full broadcast.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know about `einsum` before; this is quite elegant. Thanks!

Comment: `einsum` literally contracts the for loops as shown, there are no temporaries built.

Comment: @Daniel You seem to know just about everything about `einsum`! How come?

Comment: `einsim` translates the indexing string into a `nditer` object (C api), and does a sum of products with that iteration. In this example the iteration is over the 3d index space of `m,n,d`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I've hacked a bit on the function and wrote the `optimize` code.

Comment: @Daniel I suppose that would explain it. Excuse me, just a little bit awestruck.

Answer (score 4):

In these cases, it is always good to consider `numba`, which can provide the best of both worlds:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

def vanilla_mult(R, S):
    m, n = R.shape[0], S.shape[1]
    result = np.empty((m, n), dtype=R.dtype)
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            result[i, j] = np.dot(R[i, :], S[i, j,:])
    return result

def broadcast_mult(R, S):
    return np.sum(R[:, np.newaxis, :] * S, axis=2)

@jit(nopython=True)
def jit_mult(R, S):
    m, n = R.shape[0], S.shape[1]
    result = np.empty((m, n), dtype=R.dtype)
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            result[i, j] = np.dot(R[i, :], S[i, j,:])
    return result
```

Note, `vanilla_mult` and `jit_mult` have the exact-same implementation, however, the latter is just-in-time compiled. Let's test this out:

```
In [1]: import test # the above is in test.py

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: m, n, d = 100, 100, 100

In [4]: R = np.random.rand(m, d)

In [5]: S = np.random.rand(m, n, d)
```

OK...

```
In [6]: %timeit test.broadcast_mult(R, S)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.95 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit test.vanilla_mult(R, S)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.7 ms per loop
```

Ouch, yeah, an almost 5-fold increase in compuation time compared to broadcasting. However...

```
In [8]: %timeit test.jit_mult(R, S)
The slowest run took 760.57 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1 loop, best of 3: 870 µs per loop
```

Nice! We can cut our runtime in half by simply JITing! How does this scale?

```
In [12]: m, n, d = 1000, 1000, 100

In [13]: R = np.random.rand(m, d)

In [14]: S = np.random.rand(m, n, d)

In [15]: %timeit test.vanilla_mult(R, S)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.22 s per loop

In [16]: %timeit test.broadcast_mult(R, S)
1 loop, best of 3: 666 ms per loop

In [17]: %timeit test.jit_mult(R, S)
The slowest run took 7.59 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1 loop, best of 3: 83.6 ms per loop
```

Scales *very* well, since broadcasting is starting to be held back by having to create large, intermediate arrays, it is only half the time compared to the vanilla approach, but it takes almost 7-times as much as the JIT-approach!

#### Edit to Add

And finally, we compare the `np.einsum` approach:

```
In [19]: %timeit np.einsum('md,mnd->mn', R, S)
10 loops, best of 3: 59.5 ms per loop
```

And it is clearly the winner in speed. I am not familiar enough with it to comment on the space requirements, though.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! I've never heard of numba before; will try it out.